# ReactJS - Image isn't loaded

Tags: javascript, image, reactjs, object

I am trying to setup a react component called `FullscreenImage` that displays my image as 100% of the width/height in parallax style. As I am going to use this component more often, I thought it would be a good idea to pass the URL for the picture via props. The problem is that if I pass the URL as a prop, it doesnt load the image, but just inserts the URL. How can I also load the picture? I saw on my Webpage, that statically inserted URLs translate into URLs with the prefix `static/media/`.

FullscreenImage.jsx

```
 let defaultStyle = {
    minHeight: '100vh !important',
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundAttachment: 'fixed',
    backgroundPosition: 'center',
    backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
    backgroundSize: 'cover',
    overflow: 'hidden'
};

class FullscreenImage extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            defaultStyle: defaultStyle,
            background: {}
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({background: this.props.source.uri});
    }

    render() {
        console.log(this.state);
        return (<div style={{
                ...defaultStyle,
                backgroundImage: this.state.background
            }}></div>);
    }
}
export default FullscreenImage;
```

App.jsx

```
let picture1 = {
    uri: "url(../img/austin-neill-247237-unsplash.jpg)"
};

class App extends Component {

    render() {
        return (<section>
            <FullscreenImage source={picture1}>
            </section>);
    }
}
export default Login;
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. You can't pass the URL directly to an children component, because react expects an imageObject. You first need to import the picture using:

```
import pictureOne from '../img/austin-neill-247237-unsplash.jpg';
let picture1 = {
    uri: pictureOne
};
```

and then (as stated in @David Guans answer) add the URL prefix to let HTML know it's an image from this URL.

`backgroundImage: 'url(' + this.state.background + ')'` (using the ES5 way in here)

Also I forgot to set a height to my image so it wouldn't be displayed. I just updated my `defaultStyle` object with `minHeight: 100vh`

```
let defaultStyle = {
    minHeight: '100vh',
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundAttachment: 'fixed',
    backgroundPosition: 'center',
    backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
    backgroundSize: 'cover',
    overflow: 'hidden'
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to apply style for the background image, you need to add **url** in the front followed by the image path or image url.

check this sample code which displays the image note that you will need to add width and height to it according to your requirement

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css'

let defaultStyle = {
  minHeight: '500px',
  width: '500px',
  display: 'flex',
  flexDirection: 'column',
  justifyContent: 'center',
  backgroundAttachment: 'fixed',
  backgroundPosition: 'center',
  backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
  backgroundSize: 'cover',
  overflow: 'hidden',
};

class App extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super()
    this.state = {
      defaultStyle: defaultStyle,
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({background: "https://www.npmjs.com/static/images/wombat-camper.png"});
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <div style={{...defaultStyle, backgroundImage: "url(" +this.state.background + ")"}}></div>/
        //----alternate option ES6 syntax (backgroundImage: `url${this.state.background}`)----
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

please try to replace

```
return (<div style={{
          ...defaultStyle,
          backgroundImage: this.state.background
    }}></div>
);
```

to

```
return (<div style={{
          ...defaultStyle,
          backgroundImage: `url${this.state.background}`
    }}></div>
);
```

But why?

`background-image: <string>` is not a valid HTML syntax, `background-image: <url>` is.